# Can't access services on server using it's public IP after starting Wireguard

Tags: debian, services, wireguard

If I set up my Debain server as a Wireguard client I can't connect to services running on the server from outside the local network (using it's public IP) anymore.
From the local network and as soon as I stop the Wireguard connection everything works fine.
The tcpdump log shows the requests are all reaching the server.

wg0.conf:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ...
Address = 100.64.67.64/32
DNS = 127.0.0.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = ...
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = ...
PresharedKey = ...
```

`wg-quick up wg0`:

```
[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 100.64.67.64/32 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -a wg0 -m 0 -x
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] iptables-restore -n
```

`ip -4 rule show table 51820`:

```
32765:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
```

`wg-quick down wg0`:

```
[#] ip -4 rule delete table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule delete table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] ip link delete dev wg0
[#] resolvconf -d wg0 -f
[#] iptables-restore -n
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.
The problem is of course that the request goes into eth0 but the response is sent over the Wireguard tunnel (wg1) and is reaching the client with a different IP:

```
Request: Client -> Internet -> Router [NAT] -> Server  
Response: Server -> Router [NAT] -> Internet -> VPN Provider [NAT] -> Internet -> Client
```

So you need to bypass the VPN Tunnel for these cases by adding a rule to use the main routing table instead:

```
ip rule add from <interface IP> lookup main
```

Example:

```
$ ip a
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:ed:fc:a5:65 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.2/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip rule add from 192.168.0.2 lookup main

$ ip route show table main
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 src 192.168.0.2 metric 202
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.2 metric 202

$ ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32756:  from 192.168.178.2 lookup main
32761:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32762:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

---

In my case the service it wanted to access from outside the local network was a Wireguard server. For the Wireguard clients to be able to access the local network and the internet you additionally have to add the following rule:

```
ip rule add from <Wireguard IP range> lookup main
```

Example:

```
$ ip a
11: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/none
inet 10.6.0.1/24 scope global wg0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip rule add from 10.6.0.1/24 lookup main
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with adding things to the ip routing table, does this persist across reboots?

Comment: No you have to set the routes and rules on boot up.

Comment: Instead of explicitly adding the interface IP, it's probably better to add: `ip rule add not from <Wireguard IP range> lookup main`, where any non-wireguard range address is matched, instead of explicitly matching the interface address.