# How to make wireguard exclude port 80 from tunnel

Tags: debian, routing, firewall, vpn, wireguard

I am running a Debian VPS host

My regular public IP is $A

Under Wireguard VPN my public IP is $B

I have services accessible on ports 4040 and 5050 on $B

I want to access port 80 from $A while Wireguard is tunneling all other traffic

How can I do this?

I have thus far unsuccessfully tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/706286/383057), [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/608140), and [these](https://chat.openai.com/share/2f1476f0-264f-48d9-9cca-25aa824bf54b)

Comment: I would like to add that the linked chat log was using randomly generated IPs and placeholder ports. Please do not edit it away.

Answer (score 0):

`ip -6 route add default via $gateway_address dev eth0 table $TABLE`

`ip -6 rule add from $public_ipv6_address table $TABLE`

where $gateway_address is found in /etc/network/interfaces

and $TABLE is added in /etc/iproute2/rt_tables (200  $TABLE)

I've added the following line after my [Interface] section in my wg.conf
`PostUp = ip -6 route add default via fe80::1 dev eth0 table NOVPN && ip -6 rule add from 2a01:4f8:c012:52da::1 table NOVPN`